# Eclipse unresolved includes

Tags: eclipse

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey,

I'm trying to use Eclispe (Indigo) with ROS (Hydro). I can import my packages but I still have inresolved includes.
I followed the [Turorial](http://wiki.ros.org/IDEs) but I'm not able to do this step:

> In Eclipse, right click the project,
> click properties -> C/C++ general ->
> Preprocessor Include Paths, Macros
> etc. Click the tab "Providers" and
> check the box next to "CDT GCC
> Built-in Compiler Settings [ Shared
> ]".

When I click on porperties -> c/c++ general there is no Preprocessor Include Paths, Macros etc.

Is there any way to solve this problem in another way?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/211064/eclipse-unresolved-includes/) by [hannjaminbutton](https://answers.ros.org/users/22033/hannjaminbutton/) on ROS Answers with karma: 65 on 2015-06-11

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Did you click on the small black triangle next to `C/C++ General`? If you clicked on just `C/C++ General` it should just say "Enable Project Specific Settings" which is not the option you want.

On Eclipse Luna, which is what I'm using, under C/C++ General it says: `>Code analysis`, `Documentation`, `File Types`, `Formatter`, `Indexer`, `Language Mapping`, `Preprocessor Include Paths` and `Profiling Catagories`.

If any of those are missing, you might want to consider using a more recent version of eclipse.

If adding `CDT GCC Built-in Compiler Settings [ Shared ]` doesn't fix your problem, make sure to check Project -> Properties -> C/C++ Include Paths and Symbols, and see if `/usr/include/c++/4.x` and `/usr/include/c++/4.x/backward` are in there. 4.x for me was 4.8. Check yours by using your file manager and going to /usr/include.

Remember to go to Project ->C/C++ Index after finishing.

It should be fixed by then, assuming you installed eclipse and ran it from terminal with `bash -i -c "eclipse`

---

Originally posted by [raghav.rao32](https://answers.ros.org/users/22735/raghav.rao32/) with karma: 16 on 2015-06-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hannjaminbutton](https://answers.ros.org/users/22033/hannjaminbutton/) on 2015-06-12**:
Yes, I clicked on the triangle. For my version it only says Code Style, Documentation, File Types, Indexer and Language Mapping.
I also included these paths but its still not working.
But thanks for your answer, I will get a more recent version of eclipse!

**Comment by [Reiner](https://answers.ros.org/users/22377/reiner/) on 2015-06-16**:
http://answers.ros.org/question/52013/catkin-and-eclipse/
The top rated answer will help you.
I battled with the same problem for a week. sourcing seems to be the answer